# Cant figure out why isLetterOrDigit is returning true

Tags: java

New to Java.  Trying to write a simple method that determines if Letters or Digits in a phrase using isLettersOrDigits.  Code returns the correct results for every case but as shown in the code below where there are no letters or digits provided, i.e., the string is "", the result returned is true. I would expect it to be false. Any insight as to what I am not understanding would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

```
public class Methods {

public boolean isValid(String name) {
    char[] chars = name.toCharArray();

    for (char c : chars) {
        if (!Character.isLetterOrDigit(c)) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Methods method3 = new Methods();
    boolean response = method3.isValid("");

    System.out.println("The string entered contains only alpha or digits : " + response);
}
```

}

Comment: because `char[] chars` is empty, so your for loop is not even entered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing an empty string to your method there is nothing to convert to a character, so the loop is never entered and it defaults to true. You should perform a conditional check to make sure the string is parsable. I prefer early return logic myself but there are multiple ways to achieve this.

```
public boolean isValid(String name) {
   // Early return if null or empty string
   if(name == null || name.isEmpty()){
       return false;
    }

    char[] chars = name.toCharArray();

    for (char c : chars) {
        if (!Character.isLetterOrDigit(c)) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: @Jonn Mc You can only checkmark a single answer, and this answer does not take into account `null` so it will still throw an NPE.

Comment: Good point for correctness I will edit to include NPE.

Answer (score 3):

Your `for` loop will never be entered in two different cases: `null` and an empty `String`.

The `null` case will give you a `NullPointerException` and halt the execution, while an empty `String` will give you a `char` array of size 0 so the `for` loop does not iterate a single time.

I would just use an `if` statement at the beginning to cover the corner cases of `null` and an empty `String`:

```
public boolean isValid(String name) {
    if (name == null || name.length() == 0) {
        return false;
    }
    
    for (char c : name.toCharArray()) {
        if (!Character.isLetterOrDigit(c)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

This will give you the expected results of `false` for `null` or an empty `String`.

Sidenote:

The order of the checks in `if (name == null || name.length() == 0)` matter, if you attempt to do `if (name.length() == 0 || name == null)`, you will still get `NullPointerException` on `name.length()` because the arguments are read left to right.

Comment: In Java 11+, [`String#isBlank`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#isBlank()).

Comment: Thank you.  Figured it was something relatively easy and obvious.

Answer (score 1):

You are using a `forEach` iterator. This means if nothing is there to iterate (String length 0), it will skip the loop.

```
public static boolean isValid(String name) {
    if (name == null || name.isBlank()) {
      return false;
    }
    char[] chars = name.toCharArray();

    for (char c : chars) {
        if (!Character.isLetterOrDigit(c)) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Note that I changed the method to a static method. This means it can be called without the need of creating an instance of Methods. It is the recommended way for utility classes such as this one.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    boolean response = Methods.isValid("");

    System.out.println("The string entered contains only alpha or digits : " + response);
}
```

Comment: OP didn't specify case for `null`, but this will throw an NPE if `null` is passed.

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

Use code points, not `char`.

Using streams instead of looping.

```java
public static boolean isValidName ( String name ) {
    if ( Objects.isNull( name ) ) { return false; }
    return name.codePoints().allMatch( codePoint -> Character.isLetterOrDigit( codePoint ) );
}
```

Using looping instead of streams.

```java
public static boolean isValidName ( String name ) {
    if ( Objects.isNull( name ) ) { return false; }
    boolean valid = false;  // Default to false in case the string is empty or full of whitespace characters.
    int[] codePoints = name.codePoints().toArray();
    for ( int codePoint : codePoints ) {
        if ( Character.isLetterOrDigit( codePoint ) ) {
            valid = true;
        } else {  // Else this code point does *not* represent a letter or digit.
            return false;
        }
    }
    return valid;
}
```

## Code point integers, not `char`

The other Answers are correct in pointing out that you must test for null or empty strings. They are wrong in using `char`. The `char` type is obsolete. Less than half the characters defined in [Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) and supported in Java can be represented via `char`. Instead, learn to use Unicode [code point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point) numbers.

In Unicode, every one of the 143,859 characters identified by the Unicode Consortium is assigned a number. Those numbers are assigned from a pool with a range of 0 to over a million. So, obviously, most of the numbers are unassigned, reserved for future use or [private use](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_Use_Areas).

Calling [`String#codePoints`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#codePoints()) gives us a [`IntStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html), a stream of `int` primitive values, one per character in the string.

```
IntStream intStream = "Hello".codePoints() ;
```

Test each of those code point numbers to see if the character it represents is a letter or digit as defined by Unicode.

```java
intStream.forEach( codePoint -> System.out.println(
        "Character: " + Character.toString( codePoint ) +
                " at code point: " + codePoint +
                " is a letter or digit: " + Character.isLetterOrDigit( codePoint )
) );
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/rPJ9JL).

```
Character: H at code point: 72 is a letter or digit: true
Character: e at code point: 101 is a letter or digit: true
Character: l at code point: 108 is a letter or digit: true
Character: l at code point: 108 is a letter or digit: true
Character: o at code point: 111 is a letter or digit: true
Character:  at code point: 128567 is a letter or digit: false
```

## Streams

Now we can use similar code to implement your `isValidName` method.

```java
package work.basil.uni;

import java.util.Objects;

public class App {
    public static void main ( String[] args ) {
        String name = "Basil" ;  
        boolean isValidName = App.isValidName( name );
        System.out.println( "isValidName = " + isValidName );
    }

    public static boolean isValidName ( String name ) {
        Objects.requireNonNull( name , "The name argument must be a `String` object, not null. Message # dc809f31-aad0-449a-a0db-3e7e79ed1808." );
        if ( name.isBlank() ) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException( "The name argument must have some text rather than empty or full of whitespace. Message # bd16cb1f-17b3-47d0-9ec8-5cb2d97d2bb2." );
        }
        return ! name.codePoints().anyMatch( codePoint -> ! Character.isLetterOrDigit( codePoint ) );
    }
}
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/S1JcdE).

> false

The above code assumes you want to throw exceptions for null or empty strings. If you do not, let’s rewrite the test. In this test we call [`Stream#allMatch`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#allMatch(java.util.function.Predicate)) rather than [`Stream#anyMatch`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#anyMatch(java.util.function.Predicate)).

```java
public static boolean isValidName ( String name ) {
    if ( Objects.isNull( name ) ) { return false; }
    return name.codePoints().allMatch( codePoint -> Character.isLetterOrDigit( codePoint ) );
}
```

## Looping

If you are not familiar with streams, you can use a loop.

the [method-chaining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining) calls `name.codePoints().toArray()` first creates an `IntStream` of our Unicode code point integer numbers, and then collects those `int` values into an array of `int`.

Our *for-each* syntax in the `for` loop examines each element in that array. Each `int` is tested to see if it meets the test of being an letter or digit.

Notice that we default `valid` to `false`. This handles the case where the input string is either empty.

Notice that we bail out of the `for` loop as soon as we encounter the first non-letter/digit character.

```java
public static boolean isValidName ( String name ) {
    if ( Objects.isNull( name ) ) { return false; }
    boolean valid = false;
    int[] codePoints = name.codePoints().toArray();
    for ( int codePoint : codePoints ) {
        if ( Character.isLetterOrDigit( codePoint ) ) {
            valid = true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return valid;
}
```

We could skip the assignment to `codePoints`, not that I necessarily recommend doing so.

```java
public static boolean isValidName ( String name ) {
    if ( Objects.isNull( name ) ) { return false; }
    boolean valid = false;
    for ( int codePoint : name.codePoints().toArray() ) {
        if ( Character.isLetterOrDigit( codePoint ) ) {
            valid = true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return valid;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the string "" has no characters,

```
char[] chars = name.toCharArray();
```

produces an empty char array.

Therefore, the for-loop that follows has no iterations. If you need the edge case of an empty input string to return `false`, you could check for this edge case at the beginning of your `isValid` function:

```
public boolean isValid(String name) {
    if (name == null || name.length() == 0)
        return false;

    char[] chars = name.toCharArray();

    for (char c : chars) {
        if (!Character.isLetterOrDigit(c)) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: The `null` check of `name` at the end of the method is pointless, since you would have already encountered an NPE on the first line of the method (on `name.toCharArray()`).